# How to prohibit updating Android studio versions ？

Tags: android-studio

How to completely prohibit Android Studio from updating versions, as it is always secretly updating versions automatically, even if it has already been disabled!

I tried uninstalling Android Studio and then installing it to update the previous version, but it still displayed the latest version after installation